# Node.js fails to install on Mac: "`openpty` was not declared"

Tags: macos, installation, node.js, makefile

Trying to install the latest Node.js, when I do `make install` the build fails with the error

```
../src/node_stdio.cc: In function ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value> node::OpenPTY(const v8::Arguments&)’:
../src/node_stdio.cc:262: error: ‘openpty’ was not declared in this scope
```

Any idea what could be causing this? I've tried the current Node master, Node 0.4.3, and 0.4.2 (which I'd installed previously). Clearly, something changed on my system to interfere with the build, but what? I'm running Mac OS 10.6 with XCode 3.2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing your issue, but I reccommend you look into this installer for Node.js and OSX:
https://sites.google.com/site/nodejsmacosx/

The package will also install NPM, the node package manager. Nice and easy.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm using that as a workaround for the time being, though it would certainly be nice to know the original cause of the problem. I'd prefer to have a standard installation (and be able to install from source) rather than relying on those binaries.

Comment: Accepting this answer, but still hoping to find an explanation for the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am the person that provides the binary packages at https://sites.google.com/site/nodejsmacosx/

They are actually pretty vanilla installs. All I do is

```
  ./configure --prefix=/usr
  make
  make DESTDIR=/User/philipp/NodeJS/files install
```

and then run the Package Maker over it. So there is no real magic involved and all defaults are kept. This way all the documentation is actually valid for your install.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install Node.js, as well as other *nix tools for Mac. See if that helps.

Apparently this [was a known issue](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.nodejs/16303), but appears to have been fixed.

Comment: Ha, so I actually started out using Homebrew, raised [this issue](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/4794/) yesterday, then found that installing Node directly had the same result. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue yesterday and asked in node.js IRC. What worked for me was to switch to the v0.4 branch. I was then able to compile with no issues.

Comment: Dang. I'm checking my versions, noticed I am on OS 10.6.6 with xCode 3.2.4, so I do have some slight version difference from you perhaps. I may see about updating it all.